# Heuristic to detect if an HTML email was read

Tags: php, email, html-email, newsletter

I am looking for creative heuristics to detect if an HTML email was not just opened, but also likely *read*.

Currently, we embed an `img` tag linking to a PHP script, which marks *anonymously* in the database that the email was opened. (We can assume here that the users we're interested in told Outlook it was OK to display the images.)

This method is okay, but it's hard to tell what it means - if they clicked the email just to get it marked as read, if they keyed through it while skipping through other mails, or if they genuinely read and enjoyed the email.

My latest try was to implement a delay of 10 seconds on the image download before making the database call marking the mail as read, however it seems that Outlook finishes the request in the background, even if they skip out of the email. **Does anyone have any creative recommendations that may work better?**

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of unethical in my opinion to do this without your user's knowing. That's why so many email clients go to measures to protect against this.

I know this might not really help you, but if your user genuinely read and enjoyed the email couldn't you just add an HTML anchor in the email that they can click on to go to your website and you can add a tracking code to that to figure out who it was / which email address clicked on the link at the bottom of your email. Something along those lines just seems like a better method to me. Maybe that's just me though.

Comment: It has potential to be unethical -- you're right there -- but in my organization, the stats are anonymous and beyond that, the users can always choose to not accept the images in their client. So, in short, there are ways to do this without violating privacy.

Comment: There are definitely ways to avoid it, but unless your average user knows more than my average user about networking they have no idea why they would want to block images. If the stats are aggregate though than it's really not that unethical. I can see how that could be useful without invading the user's privacy. I don't have any creative solutions though. The link at the bottom was my best, and it's not all that creative haha.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, tough one without the use of javascript, and as we know, most email clients have their security too high to use javascript.

Not putting much thought into it, could you use PHP's shutdown function, and have the image "loop" load....basically meaning that the image will never completely load because we are stopping it on the server side with a loop.  Will Outlook still try and download the image after a timeout - will it timeout?

It seems like you are dealing with two different issues...trying to harness Outlook and trying to do something that most people don't want.

This is why there are offers and links like "click here for 10% off coupon" or "read more".

From a marketing standpoint this would be a true test if people are interested in your emails....but I guess that wasn't your question ;)

Comment: Interesting, but wouldn't the script timeout in the same way whether they _opened it_ or _opened it and then navigated away_?

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure.  :)  I think my thought here was that if the image never finished loading, then maybe you could track how long the connection was opened for with the regsiter_shutdown_function() http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php.  And when they navigated away, then the connection would be broke. I'm pretty sure that function can be setup to run even after the connection has been broken on the server which you could then use to log the result.  Again, this would all depend on how long the email client wants to sit there and try resolve the image.